# Retaining a value obtained from file within the return value of a method

Tags: c#, variables, file-access

Assuming I will need to access the values contained within a given file a small number of times, from different methods, can I include some sort of boolean value within a method to determine whether or not it is appropriate to call the file?

Lets say I have the file *config.cfg*. In that file, there are three values:

```
string/name>max|
bool/adult>yes|
int/age>20|
```

The method `getUserName()` returns the value of `"max"`. It does this by calling the file:

```
using (StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(path))
{
    //get line beginning with string/name here
    return //string value containing name
}
```

Let's assume I need to use the value of `name` several times, as well as the values `isAdult` and `clientAge`. Rather than accessing the file over and over again, it could be much easier to save the requested value in some form of static variable. However, this variable still needs to be changed in value at least once, when the method is first called.

Can I do this *inside* the method `getUserName()`?
Furthermore, is this idea even possible within the bounds of OOP? Is it a similar concept to Prefetch?

Comment: You might want to create a singleton class that parses the file and has those values as properties.  The first time you access the class it would load the file and then in future access would be in memory.

Comment: why not a static, and set it with an initial value null.  Simple, clean, and despite what the purists say that is a proper (in fact a specifically designed intention of the c# language definition) use of static variables.

Comment: @Rob because this requires an additional object within the class. I'm trying to do everything inside the single method, as and when needed, rather than creating a separate value for `Name`. This means that if I'm performing a function that doesn't require some of the data contained within the file, I don't have to access it. FYI I'm targeting embedded platforms here, hence the necessity for streamlining.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It really looks to me that you  need to access a field in a lazy way (i.e. only if needed, when needed). If so .NET has Lazy class for such cases which also provides thread safety out of the box:

```
public static Lazy<string> Name { get; } = new Lazy<string>(() => ReadNameFromFile());
```

Lazy will also ensure that you only create value once (i.e. call initiailization method) and on later calls it will simply return already retrieved value.

Answer (score 0):

Create a static class. Something like this:

```
 public static class ClientConfig{

    public static string Name{get;set;}
    public static bool IsAdult{get;set;}
    public static int Age{get;set;}

     public static void Load(){
     // load your values 
    // ClientConfig.Name = name from file etc.
    }


    public static void Save(string newName, int age, bool value){
     // save your values to the config file
    }
    }
```

And call ClientConfig.Load() first time when your app starts, for example (or whenever you need to retrieve config data)

Comment: Can you expand on how this works? How does the get/set functionality apply here?

Comment: This is basic OOP. Name, IsAdult and Age are class properties (in this exampe they are static).  Please read more about [class properties here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/classes-and-structs/using-properties) and what is [static](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/static)